# Use all of the following symbols and numbers in one equation

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Use all of the following symbols and numbers in one equation for the result to be equal to 10

> (14, 12, 9 , 7, 3) (÷ × - ÷)

Comment: Any limits on using parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

> $12 ÷ 3 = 4$
> $9 - 4 = 5$
> $14 ÷ 7 = 2$
> $5 * 2 = 10$

And in one equation (assuming the two parentheses around the symbols are included):

> $(9 - 12 ÷ 3) * 14 ÷ 7 = 10$

Comment: Even more precisely, that should be written without parentheses enclosing 12/3 or 14/7 since only _two_ pairs of parentheses are given.

Comment: @trolley813 I'm not sure if the parenthenses are part of the symbols included, or if they are just showing the set of symbols because there's parentheses around the numbers too. Thanks for the suggestion! The equation does now work with just two parentheses, assuming those are included

Answer (score 0):

## With no parentheses

> I checked all arrangments; no solution.

## With one parenthesis pair

> I didn't check exhaustively for *all* solutions, but these work.
>  $$(9-3/7)/12*14 = 10$$
>  $$(9-3/7)*14/12 = 10$$
>  $$(9-12/3)/7*14 = 10$$
>  $$(9-12/3)*14/7 = 10$$

## With two parenthesis pairs

> If the answer really must have two pairs of parentheses because they are among the symbols shown along with the numbers and operators, then we can trivially convert the one-pair solutions to match that.
>  $$(9-3/7)/12*(14) = 10$$
>  $$(9-3/7)*(14/12) = 10$$
>  $$(9-12/3)/7*(14) = 10$$
>  $$(9-12/3)*(14/7) = 10$$